# MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have created Two Node. Node1 has Peer0.org1, CA and Orderer Service and Node2 have Peer0.org2 and Peer0.org3.

I can invoke and execute a query using fabric-client from peer0.org1 but When I tried same from peer0.org2 and peer0.org3 it's not working using API and it throws **MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority** error. However it's working from the CLI

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the endorsement policy on the chaincode. Most of the times this error is because your org2 and org3 are not part of endorsement policy.